# How to get Youtube video in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, iframe, youtube

I have this embedded video in my iframe

`<iframe id="Frustrated" width="560" height="315"` `src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mjQwedC1WzI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>`

With a usual video, you would get something like

```
$('#Frustrated').get(0)
```

to get the video and call a function with it.

However, when I try to do this with a YouTube video this does not work. I read on the Google development page that one should set up the API and follow from that. However, I have never used API and I am finding this whole thing very confusing.

This is the jQuery I have at the moment and that I am trying to make work on the iframe.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var video = $('section iframe').get(0);

    video.onended = function(e) {
      $('section iframe').animate({ width: "50%"}, 'slow', function(){
          $('#information').fadeIn('slow');
      });
    }

    video.onplay = function(e) {
        $('#information').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('section iframe').animate({ width: "100%" }, 'slow');
    });
    }

    $('section iframe').click(function() {

        if(this.paused || this.ended){
            $('#information').fadeOut('slow', function(){
           $('section iframe').animate({ width: "100%" }, 'slow', function(){
           video.play();
           });
            });
        } 

        else if (this.play) {
          video.pause();
          $('section iframe').animate({ width: "50%" }, 'slow');
              $('#information').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    });
});
```

Would anyone be able to explain how to proceed?

Comment: You have some elements involved, so please post the HTML along with the jQuery in a  [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look for
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

And without iframes
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=es